# com.wwl.canvas - Attempt to read from field on a null object

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, appcelerator

I'm using Appcelerator for developing for Android devices. Since I need to draw some lines, I downloaded and install "com.wwl.canvas" module on my project. When I do try the app.js example on my project, everything is working... anyway when I write this code:

```
var Canvas = require('com.wwl.canvas');
var canvas = Canvas.createCanvasView({
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        right: "20dp",
        bottom: "80dp",
        top: "20dp",
        left: "20dp",
        zIndex: 10
    });

overlay.add(canvas);

var shapes = [
    {
        name: 'polygon',

        fn: function(){
            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.lineWidth = 7;
            canvas.strokeStyle = 'blue';
            canvas.drawLine(0,0,400,400);
            canvas.drawLine(400,400,400,300);
            canvas.drawLine(400,300,800,300);
            canvas.drawLine(800,300,700,200);
            canvas.drawLine(700,200,0,0);
        }
    } 

    ];

shapes[0].fn();
```

it says: "Attempt to read from field 'com.wwl.canvas.CanvasView$CView com.wwl.canvas.CanvasView.cView' on a null object reference
at com.wwl.canvas.CanvasViewProxy.beginPath(CanvasViewProxy.java:109)
...."

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you add all the jar etc libraries?

Comment: Yes the module is well imported because when I substitute temporary my app.js with the sample one is working. 
When I'm using my app.js writing the code above it does not give any error the "var Canvas = require('com.wwl.canvas');" and neither the rest of the code... just when the code arrives at "shapes[0].fn();" and goes at the line "canvas.beginPath();" I got that error. 
From the error it seems that creating the Canvas with this code return a null object: var canvas = Canvas.createCanvasView({...
But this is the same code that is written in the sample app ...

Comment: then it could be fairly complex problem, reading the error it seems to me either there is issue with access (whether classes are private or public) or you cant get that class in that view. You need someone to know Android and Appcelerator fairly well. Putting the full error and more of your code might help.